# Question regarding pointers in fscanf

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I am using C. I am having issues with using pointers for the fscanf function. When I try to do:

```
int *x;
/* ... */
fscanf(file, "%d", x[i]);
```

My compiler gives me a warning saying "format argument is not a pointer" and the code just doesn't run (I get a message saying "Water.exe has stopped working"). If I replace x with *x, it just doesn't compile... Is this just a syntax issue?

Comment: I suspect that something important is happening in the "...". Can you show us the complete version of the smallest program you can get to do it? That is copy the program, strip out as much as possible while still getting the error.

Comment: Also in that versino please state what do you wish to do, there are too many "doesn't work" around.

Comment: Both `*x` and `x[i]` are type `int`, not type `int *` as expected by `fscanf(file, "%d"...)`. So yes, this is fundamentally a syntax error. Assuming you allocated enough space pointed at by `x`, that is, in which case you wanted to write `fscanf(file, "%d", &x[i])` or equivalently `fscanf(file, "%d", x+i)`.

Comment: @RBerteig - It's not a syntax error, because `fscanf()` is a varargs function, so there is no type-checking at compile time. A good compiler _can_ perform compile-time type checking, but doesn't have to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to read a single integer, do this:

```
int x;
fscanf(file, "%d", &x );
```

If you want, you could do this to read a single integer in a dynamically-allocated variable:

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
fscanf(file, "%d", x );
```

If you want an array of integers, do this:

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int) * DESIRED_ARRAY_SIZE);
fscanf(file, "%d", &x[i] );
```

`%d` expects a pointer to an `int`, but `x[i]` is an `int`, so you need to take the address of your list element using the address-of operator (unary `&`).

Comment: +1 for including a sample demonstrating the address of an array element which seems to me to be the source of the OP's confusion.

Answer (score 8):

You need to allocate some space for the results.

```
int *x; // declares x

x = malloc( 600000 * sizeof(int) ) // and allocates space for it

for (int i = 0; i < 600000; ++i ) {
    fscanf(file, "%d", &x[i] ); // read into ith element of x
}
```

Comment: I've tried to allocate space by doing the following:
x = (int *) calloc(600000, sizeof(int));

However, that still doesn't work...

Comment: What you show is the proper way to do it, this isn't but goes to illustrate what is the OP doing wrong: int *x; x = malloc(sizeof(int)); fscanf(file, "%d", x); would work.

Comment: Given that the OP is trying to read values into `x[i]`, I think he wants an array, rather than a single `int`.

Comment: @Chris -- the question changed out from under my answer.

Comment: @Vinko -- I had actually typed that in as an alternative, but omitted it to try and avoid confusion.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I had made a typo. I realized that after reading your answer. Thanks anyways, though.

Comment: @wolfPack88 -- when you use x[i] you are actually passing the value stored at x[i], not a reference to it.  Dereference it to get the address in which to put the value, &x[i].

Comment: Updated with example using array.